# UINavigationBar: Adding navigation bar not able to change color or title

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I add it a UINavigationBar on interface builder on my story board but I want to change the color and title of the UINavigationBar programmatically but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"New Title";
```

Any of you knows why this happening or a way around this?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: If you do it in the Navigation root/master view controller, then    `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];`

Comment: What is your root view controller of the navigation controller?

Comment: Don't add a nav bar directly. Put the view controller inside a `UINavigationController`. Then the code you posted will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

These kinds of things can also be done in interface builder when you have access to the reference (and previewed)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]};
```

if you want to change navigation bar background color,
use

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use these code to change the navigationbar in global.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:RGB(248, 248, 248)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:COLOR_NAV_GLOBAL}];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_back"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_back"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:33.0/255.0 green:30.0/255.0 blue:94.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
```

put this in the view did load method.
first one is for the navigation bar tint color and the second one is for the title font color.